# Why is my continue keyword in my do-while loop not working?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm just starting to learn C# and I'm trying to create a really simple program about knowing the DayOfWeek of a specific Date. The continue keyword in the do-while loop doesn't work for error checking.

I have tried doing another way of error checking, by including the conditions directly inside the while loop, but I'm curious why the continue doesn't work.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int yearInput, monthInput, dateInput;
            Console.WriteLine("We can tell you any day of any date");
            bool correctInput;


            //the problem starts at dateInput request (the third do while loop)

            do { Console.WriteLine("\nSet a year :");
                correctInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out yearInput);

                if (!correctInput)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Input!");

                }
            }

            while (!correctInput);

            // this part is where is starts

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSet a month :");
                correctInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out monthInput);
                if (!correctInput || monthInput < 1 || monthInput > 12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Input!");

                }
            }
            while (!correctInput || monthInput < 1 || monthInput > 12);



            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSet a date :");
                correctInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dateInput);
                if (!correctInput || dateInput > 31 || dateInput < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Input!");

                }
                else
                {

                    if (dateInput > DateTime.DaysInMonth(yearInput, monthInput))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The date doesn't reach that many!");
                        continue;


                    }

                }
            } while (!correctInput || dateInput > 31 || dateInput < 1);

            DateTime day = getDayofDate(yearInput, monthInput, dateInput);
            Console.WriteLine("\nIt is {0}.", day.DayOfWeek);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        static public DateTime getDayofDate (int year, int month, int day)
        {
            return new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }


    }
```

I expect it to repeat the loop after it meets the error, but it shows ArgumentsOutOfRangeException instead.

Comment: Hi, I just copied your code and pasted it in a new project: It worked as expected for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `continue` **works**, but still checks the loop's condition. However, the condition is `false` - the loop stops! To fix that, you can set `correctInput` to `false`, and also you can remove the `continue` - because there are no more statements after the `if` to execute (the computer automatically goes to the next iteration):

```
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nSet a date :");
            correctInput = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out dateInput);
            if (!correctInput || dateInput > 31 || dateInput < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Input!");

            }
            else
            {

                if (dateInput > DateTime.DaysInMonth(yearInput, monthInput))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The date doesn't reach that many!");
                    correctInput = false; // Makes one more iteration of the loop
                }

            }
        } while (!correctInput || dateInput > 31 || dateInput < 1);
```