# Continue in a do while loop

Tags: c#, do-while, continue

I have a do-while loop designed to get a number from user input in the console.
I included error checking and many optional variables to make it versatile (i.e. min and max allowed values, an array of values that must contain the input, and a params variable for any specific not allowed input values).

After redesigning the loop to use some continue statements (based on design constraints), the error checking no longer seems to be working.

```
public static int GetNumber(int min = int.MinValue, int max = int.MaxValue, string prompt = "Number", int[] permittedNums = null, params int[] exceptions)
{
    string? numString;
    int num;
    do
    {
        Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
        numString = Console.ReadLine();
        ClearConsoleLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(numString, out num)) { continue; }
        if (permittedNums != null && !permittedNums.Contains(num)) { continue; }
    } while (num < min || num > max || exceptions.Contains(num));
    return num;
}
```

I checked to make sure that my logic was correct to make sure that at least the continue statement was hit, and as far as I could tell it should have worked, but it was allowing the input to go through without running the loop again.

I already tried looking at other questions but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: variable `num` contains 0, so when you enter non numeric string - it remains 0, which is within limits and not in exceptions, so loop ends

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my continue keyword in my do-while loop not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756823/why-is-my-continue-keyword-in-my-do-while-loop-not-working)

Comment: @Ilya see my comment below - shouldn't it restart the loop when it hits continue?

Comment: @moshesilver you don't understand how `continue` works, it does not restart loop, it skips rest of loop's body, but condition is still checked

Comment: @ Ilya so is there another way to achieve the same functionality as continue in a regular loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` actually is simple `goto`, and in loops it works like this:

```
do {
    ...
    continue;
    ...
} while (condition)
```

is equivalent to:

```
do {
    ...
    goto LABEL;
    ...
    LABEL:
} while (condition)
```

so, even after continue condition is still evaluated (or in case of `for` loop - counter is increased and so on).

you have multiple options, for example you can put all your continuation conditions in while's condition (it works because of short circuit evaluation):

```
do
{
    Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
    numString = Console.ReadLine();
} while (
    !int.TryParse(numString, out num) ||
    (permittedNums != null && !permittedNums.Contains(num)) ||
    num < min ||
    num > max ||
    exceptions.Contains(num)
    );

return num;
```

but it is hard to read and modify, I'd prefer to see something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
    var numString = Console.ReadLine();

    int num;
    if (!int.TryParse(numString, out num)) { continue; }
    if (permittedNums != null && !permittedNums.Contains(num)) { continue; }
    if (num < min || num > max || exceptions.Contains(num)) { continue; }

    return num;
}
```

so, every time you have failed check - you skip `return` and start loop from the beginning

Answer (score 2):

you didn't provide detailed inputs, but this condition, iirc, wants to loop until user enters a legal number:

```cs
while (num < min || num > max || exceptions.Contains(num));
```

Let's say a simple example case, all parameters default, empty collection for `exceptions`. Once prompt starts, user enters any non-nubmer text, and `TryParse` fails. Note that `num` would be `0` on fail. `continue` gets called. Loop checks condition. Because
`Int32.MinValue < 0 < Int32.MaxValue`, no condition will be met and the loop ends, thus causing the illusion of loop not working properly. That's the catch of `TryParse`s actually, you need to consider about the `bool` returned by it instead of using `num` to check.

I suggest you write down a list of different inputs first, and think what result each of these inputs should produce, then you'll come up with the logic more clearly.

Comment: my problem occurs before reaching that part of the code.
if I try inputting a string for example then the first continue should restart the loop.
the problem is that it's not and it's accepting the string

Answer (score 2):

`continue` jumps to the next iteration of the loop, but the condition is still checked. Therefore use a boolean value to see whether it makes sense to even est for the end-sign of the loop:

```
public static int GetNumber(int min = int.MinValue, int max = int.MaxValue, string prompt = "Number", int[] permittedNums = null, params int[] exceptions)
{
    string? numString;
    int num;
    bool ended;
    do
    {
        ended = false;
        Console.Write($"{prompt}: ");
        numString = Console.ReadLine();
        ClearConsoleLine();
        if (!int.TryParse(numString, out num)) { continue; }
        if (permittedNums != null && !permittedNums.Contains(num)) { continue; }
        ended = true;
    } while ((!ended) || (num < min || num > max || exceptions.Contains(num)));
    return num;
}
```